# Running javascript function from a js file

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a Shopify website and I've added a `.js` file which holds few `javascript` functions, how can I tell a `<script>` which function to call on demand?

I've added the file to `<head>` like so:

```
<script src="/urls/for/custom-scripts.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

And I want to run different functions on different pages when the page is loaded, for example, inside `main-product.liquid` I want to run only `".aone-slide"` and on `blog.liquid` I want to run only `".ul.accordion"`, how is this possible?

I've tried to do something like that:

```
<script>
  !function(o) {
    console.log("theme.liquid last </body> script -> DOMContentLoaded");
    o.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log("DOMContentLoaded event listener added successfully!");
      $(document).on('ready', function() {
        
      });
    });
  }(document);
</script>
```

But I don't know how to continue because the name of the function or the trigger is a div/css class.

This is the file:

```
(function($) {
    $(".aone-slide").slick({
        dots: !0,
        infinite: !1,
        arrows: !1,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
    }), $("ul.accordion").accordion(), $(".slider-for").slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: !1,
        fade: !0,
        asNavFor: ".slider-nav"
    }), $(".slider-nav").slick({
        slidesToShow: 8,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: ".slider-for",
        dots: !1,
        centerMode: !1,
        focusOnSelect: !0,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 992,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 6,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }]
    })
})
```

Comment: If it's just a few pages, you could add an inline script to the foot of each page with a `window.onload` set to fire the function for that page. onload events can also be hard coded into element tags if you prefer. I can't understand any of your code but in core js it would also be fairly straight forward to extract a string from anywhere on the page (e.g. class name or id for a particular element) and use that to reference the function as a named property of the window object. `Window[functionName]()` where function name is a string or a variable holding a string value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing what a Javascript function is.

In your `.js` file you have only one function. This particular function is applying a slider (using the slick library) to different html elements. And it is doing that automatically when jQuery ($) is ready.

For example the first `.slick` call is creating the slider on the elements with class `aone-slide`.

So the first problem is this, if the `.js` is loaded (and the code you're showing seems to be correct) it should already work. It should already create the sliders, on all the pages. If it doesn't there is something missing (but I don't have enough elements to tell).

If you want to run `slick` only on the selected pages you should create functions inside your `.js` file and call them in the pages.

So your .js would become something like this

```
function slickAone(){
   $(".aone-slide").slick({
    dots: !0,
    infinite: !1,
    arrows: !1,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    });
}
```

(without `function ($)...`)

and then in your page yout put

```
<script>
 function($){
    slickAone();
 }
</script>
```